# Bootcamp Macbook Air thinks my USB 3.0 ports are USB 2.0

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, bootcamp, usb

I recently installed Windows 7 via bootcamp on my new Macbook Air. I have a Seagate USB 3.0 drive that works great in OSX but behaves strangely in Windows. Windows recognizes that it is a USB 3.0 drive, but tells me that it's connected to a USB 2.0 port. This is especially weird since I definitely have the Intel USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller installed. I used USB Device Tree Viewer and determined conclusively that Windows is operating my drive at USB 2.0 speeds. What can I do to get my speed back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you need drivers in order to have everything working fine. In this case, the bootcamp should install it for you right after Windows installation. It installs all drivers: trackpad, graphic card, webcam, USB 3.0; as well as some bootcamp utilities that allow you to use the <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> as volume keys for instance.

If you didn't get this part during your installation, you just need to use the USB-stick you installed windows with and run the bootcamp software on it (it's the only `.exe` you'll find).

**OR**

See this Apple Support page to download it again (64-bit, Mid-2013 MacBook Air): http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1721